# Do I have to be admin to create a new user in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a new user in MongoDB.
Do I do that by logging in as admin (`use admin`) and then using the command `add user` to create new user?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If no users created you can create new user without any authentification, but if you have created admin user for specific database you should authentifcate, and then perform any operation.

**[Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication):**

> If no users are configured in
>   admin.system.users, one may access the
>   database from the localhost interface
>   without authenticating. Thus, from the
>   server running the database (and thus
>   on localhost), run the database shell
>   and configure an administrative user:

```
 $ ./mongo
 > use admin
 > db.addUser("theadmin", "anadminpassword")
```

> We now have a user created for
>   database admin. Note that if we have
>   not previously authenticated, we now
>   must if we wish to perform further
>   operations, as there is a user in
>   admin.system.users.

```
 > db.auth("theadmin", "anadminpassword")
```

> We can view existing users for the
>   database with the command:

```
 > db.system.users.find()
```

> Now, let's configure a "regular" user
>   for another database.

```
 > use projectx
 > db.addUser("joe", "passwordForJoe")
```

Comment: @Mark maybe something to do with the fact that `addUser` has been deprecated? I don't know, I'm new to Mongo, but despite all the tutorials mentioning `addUser`, reading the official docs says you should use [`createUser`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#db.createUser) now. Kinda confusing as a newcomer.

Comment: I am out on search for a pymongo solution.. Please point me to any resources that solve this in pymongo..