# MongoDB connects through terminal, but not via PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I just started messing with MongoDB and everything is working great so far. I've installed the Mongo Server and the mongo.so PHP extension on my local XAMPP server (Mac).

I've managed [creating a new admin user, and a new regular user using `mongo` in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064004/while-creating-new-user-in-mongodb-it-has-to-be-created-under-admin) .

When trying to authenticate with that user via the Terminal or via MongoHub it would work just fine, but if I'd try to login throw RockMongo or just my own PHP script, it would always fail.

My guess is something is wrong with my PHP module perhaps? Any opinions?

**Edit (Some more info):**

1. When connecting with wrong information I would actually get a thrown `MongoMongoConnectionException`.
2. When I'm connecting with the correct information I'd get an empty page, or when trying with curl it would just return `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`
3. Mongo installed on the server is v1.3.0 
   [image]

Because of these two things I think this might be a messed up module. Anyone knows of this situation ?

Comment: how are you authenticating with your own PHP script?

Comment: `$conn = new Mongo("mongodb://user:pass@localhost/db");` I just get "empty response from server". It also doesn't work when just trying to use RockMongo which is a premade PHP script.

Comment: It sounds like you have installed the MongoDB server and client apps, but have not yet [installed the PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.osx).  If you create a simple PHP page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` you can check for a section showing the `mongo` extension is enabled.

Comment: @Stennie Thanks for the assistance but this isn't the problem, look at the information I added in the post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got on the #mongodb irc channel over at Freenode and get assisted by the very helpful and nice Derick who developed the PHP Module.

Eventually the problem was a faulty installation by MacPorts. I downloaded the latest Mongo driver 1.3.0 sources from http://pecl.php.net/get/mongo-1.3.0.tgz, manually compiled it and everything is working fine now.

Thanks to anyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way to connect to mongodb. It worked for me.

```
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://username:password@host:port");
```

By Default mongo port is 27017. You can also check that your php is thread safe & VC is same as the mongo_php extension. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing. Thats what I think the module is broken or something of that sort.